# How to recognize element that is located same level in XML using python when parse

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have been trying to parse XML using python at this moment and had a question also today.

Do you know how to recognize element that is located the same level in XML?

For XML example as follow :

```
<AAA>
    <BBB>1</BBB>
    <CCC>*</CCC>
    <BBB>1</BBB>  <--- need to remove
    <BBB>1</BBB>
    <CCC>*</CCC>
    <BBB>1</BBB>  <--- need to remove
</AAA>
```

I know how to delete element if it is located on the first line or the last line but
If I want to remove the BBB element that is found right below CCC, how can I do code?

Comment: If you can use lxml, it's quite easy since it supports XPath with `following-sibling`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses ElementTree.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

XML = """ 
<AAA>
    <BBB>1</BBB>
    <CCC>*</CCC>
    <BBB>2</BBB>
    <BBB>3</BBB>
    <CCC>*</CCC>
    <BBB>4</BBB>
</AAA>"""

root = ET.fromstring(XML)

# All children of AAA (siblings in document order)
children = root.findall("*")  

# Find all BBB elements that immediately follow a CCC element
to_remove = []
for i in range(1, len(children)):
    curr = children[i]
    prev = children[i-1]
    if curr.tag == "BBB" and prev.tag == "CCC":
        to_remove.append(curr)

# Remove the found BBB elements 
for elem in to_remove:
    root.remove(elem)

print(ET.tostring(root).decode("UTF-8"))
```

Output:

```
<AAA>
    <BBB>1</BBB>
    <CCC>*</CCC>
    <BBB>3</BBB>
    <CCC>*</CCC>
    </AAA>
```

Comment: Thanks for help but what if the each nodes of CCC is different ??

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by "what if the each nodes of CCC is different?".

Comment: I mean the all CCC element values are same as * at the example XML but if these value are different, does it work?

Comment: mzjn Appreciate for your help, actually i forgot this question and made code done. but i am using your code for other solution just now haha. have a great day!